# How to get the viewport element index

Tags: list, apache-flex

I use flex4 list:

```
 <component:SmoothScrollingList x="200"
           y="180"
           dataProvider="{myProvider}"
           itemRenderer="myitemdrender.FriendPageItemRender"
           id="friendPageList"
           mouseDown="friendPageList_mouseDownHandler(event)">
    <component:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout requestedColumnCount="6"/>
    </component:layout>
 </component:SmoothScrollingList>
```

as you can see, there is 6 element can see in the viewport.

so how can i know the current viewport element index?

ex:

`currentViewPortIndex` is : `[7][8][9][10][11][12]`

as far as i know , i can only know the the index that i already select by function

`list.selectedIndex`

did flex4 proivde some other function  that i  can use?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HorizontalLayout` has a [firstIndexInView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/langref/spark/layouts/HorizontalLayout.html#firstIndexInView) property.